# Look up cell value in a column where the look up value is just a sub-string in the column

Tags: excel

Suppose I have a text in cell B1 "abcd" and now I want to look that up and find if any of the rows in column A have that, how do I go about doing this. Remember all the rows in Column A have a lot of text, and not just what my cell value is, so I am just searching it as a substring.

So for example -If row A5 has a text "XYZabcd122" I want my result to show that A5 contains my look up value "abcd"

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=VLOOKUP("*" & B1 & "*",A:A,1,FALSE)
```